# Как работает такой typedef?

Tags: c, ос

В исходниках Pintos есть такая замена

```
typedef bool list_less_func (const struct list_elem *a,
                             const struct list_elem *b,
                             void *aux);
```

Зачем нужно называть bool именем функции с аргументами?
Само использование данной замены выглядит следующим образом:

```
    void
list_insert_ordered (struct list *list, struct list_elem *elem,
                     list_less_func *less, void *aux)
{
  struct list_elem *e;

  ASSERT (list != NULL);
  ASSERT (elem != NULL);
  ASSERT (less != NULL);

  for (e = list_begin (list); e != list_end (list); e = list_next (e))
    if (less (elem, e, aux))
      break;
  return list_insert (e, elem);
}
```

Совсем не понятно,как работает такое "другое имя" bool.Можете пояснить?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как эти "исходники Pintos" умудрились сделать `return list_insert (e, elem);` внутри функции, возвращающей `void`. Если `list_insert` сама возвращает `void`, то такой код был бы допустим в C++. Но в С такое не допускается никогда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут нет никакого "называть `bool`" и никакого "другого имени `bool`". Это объявление вообще не имеет никакого отношения к `bool`. Имя, которое в данном случае определяется  - это не `bool`, а именно `list_less_func`. Имя `list_less_func` будет синонимом функционального типа

```
bool (const struct list_elem *, const struct list_elem *, void *)
```

(Лирическое отступление: в современном синтаксисе языка С++ с использованием `using` этот же псевдоним можно было бы объявить как

```
using list_less_func = bool (const struct list_elem *, const struct list_elem *, void *);
```

)

Далее в коде это имя используется для объявления указателей на такой функциональный тип: `list_less_func *`.

Дополнительно можно заметить, что в списке параметров функции функциональный тип автоматически преобразуется в соответствующий указательный тип, т.е. можно было использовать просто

```
void
list_insert_ordered (struct list *list, struct list_elem *elem,
                     list_less_func less, void *aux)
```

без дополнительной `*` и эффект был бы тот же. Но автор кода решил явно указать эту `*`. Это дело его вкуса.

---

Наверное можно было включить "указательность" сразу прямо в тип `list_less_func`, т.е. изначально объявить

```
typedef bool (* list_less_func)(const struct list_elem *a,
                                const struct list_elem *b,
                                void *aux);
```

и далее в коде писать просто `list_less_func` для объявления указателя на функцию. Но и это дело вкуса.

В данном случае автора кода решил не прятать "указательность" под typedef-именем, что, в принципе, правильно.

---

На отвлеченную тему:

В данном коде смущает вот этот момент

```
return list_insert (e, elem);
```

внутри функции, возвращающей `void`. Язык С не допускает использование `return` с параметром внутри функции, возвращающей `void`. Это не допустимо даже если `list_insert` тоже возвращает `void`. В последнем случае код был бы корректным в С++, но не в С.

Answer (score 5):

Вы `typedef` не так прочитали.

```
typedef bool list_less_func (const struct list_elem *a,
                             const struct list_elem *b,
                             void *aux);
```

Здесь `list_less_func` - это псевдоним для
`bool(const struct list_elem *a, const struct list_elem *b, void *aux)`, то есть для функции, принимающей три аргумента и возвращающей `bool`.

Сооветственно, `list_less_func *less` - указатель на функцию.

Без `typedef`а он выглядел бы так:
`bool (*less)(const struct list_elem *a, const struct list_elem *b, void *aux)`.

Answer (score 4):

В C в отличии от C++ нет такого встроенного типа как `bool`. Имеется встроенный целочисленный тип `_Bool`, который принимает два значения: 1 и 0.

Однако вы можете включить в программу заголовок `<stdbool.h>`, в котором определяется макро `bool`, которое расширяется как `_Bool`.

Из стандарта C (6.2.5 Types):

> 2 An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values
>   0 and 1.

и (7.18 Boolean type and values )

> 2 The macro

```
    bool
```

> ```
> expands to _Bool.
> ```

В этом объявлении

```
typedef bool list_less_func (const struct list_elem *a,
                             const struct list_elem *b,
                             void *aux);
```

которое эквивалентно объявлению

```
typedef _Bool list_less_func (const struct list_elem *a,
                              const struct list_elem *b,
                              void *aux);
```

если убрать ключевое слово `typedef`

```
bool list_less_func (const struct list_elem *a,
                     const struct list_elem *b,
                     void *aux);
```

то получим просто объявление функции с именем `list_less_func`.

Итак, данное `typedef` вводит символическое имя `list_less_func` для типа функции, а не для имени `bool`, которое, как я уже написал, определяется в заголовке `<stdbool.h>`, то есть для типа функции

```
bool (const struct list_elem *a, const struct list_elem *b, void *aux);
```

которая имеет три параметра и возвращаемое значение `bool`.

Это позволяет в объявлении функции `list_insert_ordered` лаконично указать **тип третьего параметра**

```
void
list_insert_ordered (struct list *list, struct list_elem *elem,
                     list_less_func *less, void *aux);
```

как `list_less_func *`.

Иначе без typedef вам бы пришлось в объявлении функции `list_insert_ordered` писать очень длинное объявление  третьего параметра как, например,

```
void
list_insert_ordered (struct list *list, 
                     struct list_elem *elem,
                     bool less (const struct list_elem *, const struct list_elem , 
                                void *), 
                     void *aux);
```

или как

```
void
list_insert_ordered (struct list *list, 
                     struct list_elem *elem,
                     bool ( *less )(const struct list_elem *, const struct list_elem *, 
                               void *), 
                     void *aux);
```

Что, согласитесь, делает объявление функции `list_insert_ordered` трудно-читаемым.